# How do i get specific elements from webservice

Tags: javascript, react-native

[image][image]I want to get specific the first two elements from a webservice and print it to a console it is returning me 1000 items. Can anyone guide me on how I can print only the first two elements

```html
import React from "react";
import {StyleSheet,View,ActivityIndicator,FlatList,Text,TouchableOpacity} from "react-native";

export default class Source extends React.Component {
static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => {
return {
  title: "Source Listing",
  headerStyle: {backgroundColor: "#fff"},
  headerTitleStyle: {textAlign: "center",flex: 1}
 };
};
constructor(props) {
 super(props);
 this.state = {
   loading: false,
   items:[]
  };

}
FlatListItemSeparator = () => {
return (
  <View style={{
     height: .5,
     width:"100%",
     backgroundColor:"rgba(0,0,0,0.5)",
}}
/>
);
}

renderItem=(data)=>
<TouchableOpacity style={styles.list}>
<Text style={styles.lightText}>{data.item.name}</Text>
<Text style={styles.lightText}>{data.item.email}</Text>
<Text style={styles.lightText}>{data.item.company.name}</Text>
</TouchableOpacity>
render(){

 {
 if(this.state.loading){
  return( 
    <View style={styles.loader}> 
      <ActivityIndicator size="large" color="#0c9"/>
    </View>
)}}
return(
 <View style={styles.container}>
 <FlatList
    data= {this.state.dataSource}
    ItemSeparatorComponent = {this.FlatListItemSeparator}
    renderItem= {item=> this.renderItem(item)}
    keyExtractor= {item=>item.id.toString()}
 />
</View>
)}
}
const parseString = require('react-native-xml2js').parseString;

    fetch('http://192.168.200.133/apptak_service/apptak.asmx/Get_Item_Master')
        .then(response => response.text())
        .then((response) => {
            parseString(response, function (err, result) {
              console.log(response[0],response[1])
            });
        }).catch((err) => {
            console.log('fetch', err)
            
        })

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: "#fff"
   },
  loader:{
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: "center",
    backgroundColor: "#fff"
   },
  list:{
    paddingVertical: 4,
    margin: 5,
    backgroundColor: "#fff"
   }
});
```

I want it to be print on the console then I will modify it later to display it on the app. I am struggling to get this done  Please help

Comment: you are already printing first two console.log(response[0],response[1]), what is the problem here ?

Comment: can you specify your problem a bit more? you are already printing in console the first two item. What issue you are facing?

Comment: @Arnab it is printed in the console like this  <? I can't seem to understand why am i getting this instead of the item

Comment: @Guruparan i have edited my question and added a picture it is printed that way any suggestion why this is happening

Comment: if you are expecting a json response from api you should do `response.json()` instead of `response.text()`. as you can see, you are printing the first two characters of a html page.

Comment: What's in `http://192.168.200.133/apptak_service/apptak.asmx/Get_Item_Master`?

Comment: @Luka  The item data that i want it to print  the orignal data is in XML i have converted into JSON and the returned data is in array

Answer (score 0):

You are parsing the **response** as **string**. If you want to print the first two item in console, you can do it like this bellow:

```
fetch('http://192.168.200.133/apptak_service/apptak.asmx/Get_Item_Master')
        .then((response) => {
            console.log(response.data[0],response.data[1])
        }).catch((err) => {
            console.log('fetch', err)
            
        })
```

Comment: i am getting printed in the console  " undefined "

Comment: Lets just print  `console.log(response)`. What is printed then ?

Comment: The whole 1000 items are printed then should i share a screen shot?

Comment: one thing i would like to add is i get response in array

Comment: not really. Just share first 5 item so that I can see the structure of `response`.

Comment: just edited the question with the picture please have a look at it

Comment: maybe there is an issue. Can you parse the response to json like `response.json()` and share?

Comment: fetch[SyntaxError:JSON Parse Error:Unrecognized token '<']  this line is printed two times

Comment: What you are receiving is not json data. Without json data you can not call them like `response[0]`. Also, usually in response of an API, the data are stored in a key named `data`. so if it is a json data then you should be able to call it like `console.log(response.data[0, response.data[1])`. So I think you should communicate with the api provider to know in which format the response is being sent.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps what you need is the result?

```
parseString(response, function (err, result) {
   console.log(result) // not console.log(response)?
});
```

Using JavaScript

```js
fetch("http://192.168.200.133/apptak_service/apptak.asmx/Get_Item_Master")
.then((r) => r.text())
.then((t) => (new window.DOMParser()).parseFromString(t, "text/xml"))
.then((d) => console.log(d))
.catch((e) => console.error(e));
```